# Reading one integer at a time using python

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.7

How can I read int from a file? I have a large(512MB) txt file, which contains integer data as:

```
0 0 0 10 5 0 0 140
0 20 6 0 9 5 0 0
```

Now if I use `c = file.read(1)`, I get only one character at a time, but I need one integer at a time. Like:

```
c = 0
c = 10
c = 5
c = 140 and so on...
```

Any great heart please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
with open('in.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    for s in line.split(' '):
      num = int(s)
      print num
```

By doing `for line in f` you are reading bit by bit (using neither `read() all` nor `readlines`). Important because your file is large.

Then you split each line on spaces, and read each number as you go.

You can do more error checking than that simple example, which will barf if the file contains corrupted data.

As the comments say, this should be enough for you - otherwise if it is possible your file can have extremely long lines you can do something trickier like reading blocks at a time.

Comment: If every line is just space separated numbers, this is by far the easiest. Line by line... no mess no fuss. There really isn't a need to read one byte at a time.

Comment: If he has one line, he might break out of the memory I think.

Comment: This is awesome. Can you please update if the file contains tab rather then space?

Comment: @whoone At the python prompt, type `print str.split.__doc__`. That gives you some info on how split works. _Hint:_ the documentation there gives you a clue how to handle tab and space at the same time.

Comment: Yes I got this. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

512 MB is really not that large.  If you're going to create a list of the data anyway, I don't see a problem with doing the reading step in one go:

```
my_int_list = [int(v) for v in open('myfile.txt').read().split()]
```

if you can structure your code so you don't need the entire list in memory, it would be better to use a generator:

```
def my_ints(fname):
    for line in open(fname):
        for val in line.split():
            yield int(val)
```

and then use it:

```
for c in my_ints('myfile.txt'):
    # do something with c (which is the next int)
```

Comment: I'd be careful with the "512 MB is not that large" comment. If the file looks like the example data, there are a lot of numbers in that 512MB file, around 200 Mio numbers. What your code does is read in 512MB of data, then creates a list of 200 Mio. strings, then goes through that list to create a list of 200 Mio ints from that. Considering that python objects need more space than than just for the raw data, this will probably use several gigs of ram.

Comment: @danielkullmann turns out you'll run into problems with the size of string split() can handle long before you run out of memory, eg. asking for the first 50 words `open('input.txt').read()[:2**25].split(' ', 50)` works for me, while a "slightly" longer prefix `open('input.txt').read()[:2**26].split(' ', 50)` raises a MemoryError..

Answer (score -2):

I would do it this way:

- buffer = file.read(8192)
- contents += buffer
- split the output string by space
- remove last element from the array (might not be full number)
- replace contents with last element string
- repeat until buffer is None`

Comment: I like this if the Op does have really enormous lines.

Comment: Why 8192 bytes? Wouldn't it be more natural to read by disk block size (or memory page size) if you're going through the trouble of doing chunked reads?  Also, your outline leaves out the last int in the file..